# Ansible - get username matching gecos from data obtained via getent module

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I cannot figure out how to get username from getent module which has specific gecos field, ie. it should match on gecos. Let's say I want to get username of the user with gecos `cups unprivileged user`.

```
{
  "root":[
    "x",
    "0",
    "0",
    "root",
    "/root",
    "/bin/bash"
  ],
  "nobody":[
    "x",
    "99",
    "99",
    "Unprivileged User",
    "/dev/null",
    "/bin/false"
  ],
  "_uuidd":[
    "x",
    "999",
    "999",
    "_uuidd unprivileged user",
    "/var/empty",
    "/sbin/nologin"
  ],
  "jiri":[
    "x",
    "1000",
    "1000",
    "jiri",
    "/home/jiri",
    "/bin/bash"
  ],
  "dbus":[
    "x",
    "22",
    "22",
    "dbus unprivileged user",
    "/var/empty",
    "/sbin/nologin"
  ],
  "polkitd":[
    "x",
    "998",
    "998",
    "polkitd unprivileged user",
    "/var/empty",
    "/sbin/nologin"
  ],
  "lightdm":[
    "x",
    "997",
    "997",
    "lightdm unprivileged user",
    "/var/lib/lightdm",
    "/sbin/nologin"
  ],
  "dnsmasq":[
    "x",
    "996",
    "994",
    "dnsmasq unprivileged user",
    "/var/chroot",
    "/sbin/nologin"
  ],
  "libvirt":[
    "x",
    "995",
    "993",
    "libvirt unprivileged user",
    "/var/empty",
    "/sbin/nologin"
  ],
  "rpc":[
    "x",
    "994",
    "992",
    "rpc unprivileged user",
    "/var/empty",
    "/sbin/nologin"
  ],
  "openntpd":[
    "x",
    "993",
    "991",
    "openntpd unprivileged user",
    "/var/empty",
    "/sbin/nologin"
  ],
  "avahi":[
    "x",
    "23",
    "23",
    "avahi unprivileged user",
    "/var/empty",
    "/sbin/nologin"
  ],
  "_gitea":[
    "x",
    "992",
    "990",
    "_gitea unprivileged user - for uninstalled package gitea",
    "/var/empty",
    "/bin/false"
  ],
  "ldap":[
    "x",
    "991",
    "989",
    "ldap unprivileged user",
    "/var/lib/openldap",
    "/sbin/nologin"
  ],
  "cups":[
    "x",
    "990",
    "10",
    "cups unprivileged user",
    "/var/spool/cups",
    "/sbin/nologin"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [json_query](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#selecting-json-data-json-queries) with the function [contains](https://jmespath.readthedocs.io/en/latest/proposals/functions.html?highlight=contains#contains). For example

```
- hosts: test_01
  tasks:
    - getent:
        database: passwd
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ getent_passwd|dict2items|json_query(query) }}"
      vars:
        query: "[?value.contains(@, '{{ item }}')].key"
      loop:
        - 'Charlie &'
        - 'Bourne-again Superuser'
        - 'Owner of many system processes'
```

gives

```
ok: [test_01] => (item=Charlie &) => {
    "msg": [
        "root"
    ]
}
ok: [test_01] => (item=Bourne-again Superuser) => {
    "msg": [
        "toor"
    ]
}
ok: [test_01] => (item=Owner of many system processes) => {
    "msg": [
        "daemon"
    ]
}
```

In the query, it is possible to omit the function *contains* and compare the third item on the list. For example, the query below gives the same result.

```
      vars:
        query: "[?value[3] == '{{ item }}'].key"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also solve this using the `selectattr` filter:

```
`- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - getent:
        database: passwd
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ result.key }}"
      vars:
        result: "{{ getent_passwd|dict2items|selectattr('value.3', 'equalto', item)|first }}"
      loop:
        - 'root'
        - 'PulseAudio System Daemon'
        - 'RPC Service User'
```

Which results (on my system) in:

```
TASK [debug] *************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=root) => {
    "msg": "root"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=PulseAudio System Daemon) => {
    "msg": "pulse"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=RPC Service User) => {
    "msg": "rpcuser"
}
```